# Nginx parse and redirect to other domain

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I wanna make some redirect but for this i need to parse domain to send other domain.

My old domain url like this

http://olddomain.com/bg/some-name-part-421.html

http://olddomain.com/bg/some-name-1231.html

http://olddomain.com/bg/some-name-product-name-221.html

I want to redirect this to like this

https://www.newdomain.com/magazin/some-name-part.html

https://www.newdomain.com/magazin/some-name.html

https://www.newdomain.com/magazin/some-name-product-name.html

I try to redirect them like this on server block

```
rewrite ^(/bg/)([a-z-]+-[0-9]+)\.html$ http://www.newdomain.com/magazin/$2 permanent;
```

Not working well making redirect like this

http://www.olddomain.com/bg/chervena-borovinka-bioherba-3694.html

https://www.newdomain.com/magazin/chervena-borovinka-bioherba**-3694**

I want to delete also as last part of number and - but i dont know why not working well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^bg\/([^0-9]+(?<!-))-([0-9]+)(\.html)" "http://newdomain.com/magazin/$1$3" [R]
```

Dont forget to set the `RewriteBase`.

Heres the code: https://regex101.com/r/UdMqaQ/3/

### Nginx

```
rewrite "^/bg\/([^0-9]+(?<!-))-([0-9]+)(\.html)" "newdomain.com/magazin/$1";
```

Comment: rewrite "^/bg\/([^0-9]+(?<!-))-([0-9]+)(\.html)" "https://www.newdomain.com/magazin/$1";

it's working like this on nginx :)